# Sunflower app - Unable to understand where plantId is being set

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm studying https://github.com/android/sunflower to understand compose.

In the following snippet, I'm unable to understand how `plantId` is being initialised.
I understand the functionality of `SavedStateHandle`, but for it to retrieve saved state, it must first have been set.

```
@HiltViewModel
class PlantDetailViewModel @Inject constructor(
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    plantRepository: PlantRepository,
    private val gardenPlantingRepository: GardenPlantingRepository,
) : ViewModel() {

    val plantId: String = savedStateHandle.get<String>(PLANT_ID_SAVED_STATE_KEY)!!
```

Can you give a pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SunFlowerNavHost` contains the navhost which defines the routes of the screens. One of them is `plantDetail/{plantId}` This route has a named argument "plantId", this gets saved in the `savedStateHandle`.

Which then gets retrieved as such in the ViewModel of that screen.